# Function-Pointer in Interpreter

Tags: c, function-pointers, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building a C-Interpreter (in C++) which builds an AST. I want to give the user the opportunity to communicate with real DLLs. For example: I call a function from a DLL. This function expects an pointer to an function (to callback). There is the problem: I don't have a real address to a function, because the function which I want to give to the DLL-function only exists as node in my AST. Is there a way to solve the problem? I thought about using a proxy-like function built-in into my interpreter, which delegates to the function in my AST. The problem is, that the proxy-function must have the same signature to be callable from the DLL-function ... and i can't create dynamic functions at runtime.

Comment: I smell a homework assignment.

Comment: You could save the user's given pointer (which is just an AST node), pass the DLL a function pointer that points to a forwarding function, and then when the forwarding function is called, it would activate the code that would execute the AST node the user gave. Does that make sense and seem possible?

Comment: Thats what I mean with "proxy-function". But the forwarding function should receive the parameters (if there are any) from the caller (DLL-function). At this point, my forwarding function have to be "dynamic" (different parameters and return type)

Comment: I am afraid you will have to go for this proxy function and just resort to some assembler to process dynamic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say specifically which API/dll you're trying to use, but MOST of them provide for a `void *` (or `LPVOID` on windows) of 'user data' that is supplied along with the callback function pointer and will be passed to the callback function, along with whatever other arguments are appropriate for the callback.

What you can do is pass in a pointer to your AST as this extra pointer, and write a small wrapper function for the actual callback which converts this `void *` back into an `AST *` and then invokes your interpreter on that AST.